# Trying to get property 'page_slug' of non-object (View:) Laravel 6.*

Tags: php, laravel

I send data to all pages with Provider. I can pull data, but I get an error when sending parameters.

This is Provider

```
 public function boot()
        {
            View::share('page',Pages::all()->sortBy('page_must'));
            Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        }
```

Here I'm trying to send a parameter with data from the provider. I can print the Names here. But parameter give error.

```
     <ul>
         @foreach($page as $service)
       <li><a href="{{route('service.Index',$service->page_slug)}}">{{$service->page_title}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
     </ul>
```

And This is Controller

```
public function index($slug)
    {
        $pageList=Pages::all()->sortBy('page_must');
        $page=Pages::where('page_slug',$slug)->first();
        return view('frontend.service.index',compact('page','pageList'));
    }
```

This is Route

```
Route::get('/service/{slug}','Frontend\PageController@index')->name('service.Index');
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the data to see what your `$page` variable contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use an `@foreach()` loop when you retrieve a single model with `->first()`. You can simply access the values of `$page` directly:

```
// Controller
$page = Pages::where("page_slug", $slug)->first();

// View
<li>
  <a href="{{ route('service.Index', $page->page_slug) }}">
    {{ $page->page_title }}
  </a>
</li>
```

A quick note, `Pages` is not a good model name. Models are singular, so it should be `Page`.

Also, adjust this code:

```
// View::share('page', Pages::all()->sortBy('page_must'));
View::share('pages', Pages::all()->sortBy('page_must'));
```

In this code, you were sharing a `$page` variable to all views, but you're then passing a new `$page` variable via `compact('page')`, which will override it.

If you instead use the variable name `pages`, then you won't have this conflict, and it will be named properly to represent what the variable contains. `$page` should be a single `Page`, and `$pages` should be a `Collection` of `Page` instances. **Variable naming is important.**

Ah, one more thing. You can use the `@foreach()` with `$pages` if you adjust the code above:

```
@foreach($pages AS $sPage)
// using `$sPage` to not conflict with `$page` from `compact()`
<li>
  <a href="{{ route('service.Index', $sPage->page_slug) }}">
    {{ $sPage->page_title }}
  </a>
</li>
```

In summary, the issue here is conflicting/poorly named variables. `View::share('page', ...)` and `compact('page')` are both setting `$page` in the view, one is a `Collection`, which works as expected with `@foreach()`, the other is a single `Page` instance, which behaves differently.